# How can a tag exist as both an ordinary tag, and as a synonym?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, tag-synonyms

For example, on the Physics SE, the [biology] tag exists as both.

Here is the SEDE query to the [tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/revision/682738/851130/), and to the [synonym](https://data.stackexchange.com/physics/revision/682738/851133/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tag could be set on a post (or many posts) well before it becomes a synonym.

Once a such tag does become a synonym, we do not go and edit all posts with it in order to change it to its synonym - if someone happens to edit it, that will automatically happen, but if no one does, it will not.

The result will be that some tags that are synonyms will exist on the posts they were put on before they became synonyms.